# Incluir hora com minuto em um array de horas javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

Tenho um método que gera um array de hora numero e hora string, um para mostrar na tabela e outro para mandar no json. A questão é que eu gostaria de incluir 01:00 / 01:30 - 02:00 assim por diante.

```
function listaHorasDia() {
    var horas= [];
    for (var h = scope.horaInicio; h < (scope.horaFinal +1); h++)
        horas.push({ horaNumero: h, horaExibicao: ('00' + h).substr(-2) });
    return horas;
}
```

Gostaria que meu array ficasse da seguinte forma

```
horas = [
{horaNumero:1330, horaExibicao: '01:30'},
{horaNumero:1400, horaExibicao: '14:00'}
]
```

e assim por diante

Comment: Poderia detalhar melhor o que você quer incluir?

Comment: editei a pergunta @FelipeAvelar

Comment: Mas você já recebe isso no scope? Ou você tá querendo que, dentro do for, o incremento seja de 30 em 30 minutos?

Comment: no scope eu recebo um numero inteiro, gostaria que dentro do for fosse feito isso @FelipeAvelar

Comment: Não seria o caso de só adicionar mais um `push` no for? No caso adicionaria esse push: `horas.push({ horaNumero: h+30, horaExibicao: h.toString().substr(-2)+':30' });`?

Comment: Nesse caso eu perco a hora inteira                                                                  `0: {horaNumero: 30, horaExibicao: "0:30"}
1: {horaNumero: 31, horaExibicao: "1:30"}
2: {horaNumero: 32, horaExibicao: "2:30"}
3: {horaNumero: 33, horaExibicao: "3:30"}`

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que foi passado nos comentários, provavelmente isso resolve o seu problema:

```
function listaHorasDia() {
    var horas= [];
    for (var h = scope.horaInicio; h < (scope.horaFinal +1); h++) {
        horas.push({ horaNumero: h, horaExibicao: ('00' + h).substr(-2) });
        horas.push({ horaNumero: h+30, horaExibicao: h.toString().substr(-2) + ':30' });
    }
    return horas;
}
```